# SVG hover colors with inline CSS

Tags: css, svg

My backgound is changing color but as a block. How do I change the entire background area color on hover? Including the rounded sides...

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/Dr25D/1/

```
<style>
rect.svghover{
    fill: #4C85BD;
}
rect.svghover:hover{
    fill: #0055a5;
}

</style>
```

Each area looks like this in the SVG:

```
<a xlink:href="http://google.com" target="_top">
<path d="M431.5,242.5c0,8.008-6.492,14.5-14.5,14.5H198.5c-8.008,0-14.5-6.492-14.5-14.5l0,0
    c0-8.008,6.492-14.5,14.5-14.5H417C425.008,228,431.5,234.492,431.5,242.5L431.5,242.5z"/>
<rect x="197.5" y="236" fill="none" width="208.5" height="22.5" class="svghover"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 226.9644 247.9395)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="14">Mfg Launch</text></a>
```

Comment: Turns out you don't need <rect> in this case where the text is surrounded by a path. Remove the rects & fill the path color instead!

Comment: Post as an answer, [it works perfectly](http://jsbin.com/lapakini/1/edit). Feel free to use the jsbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need , and ifs its fine not having rectangles then, I did this:
[image: SVG Hover Issue]

I added `class="svghover"` to your path element and here is your edited fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/piyushkmr/Dr25D/2/